# How to get this image to align centre only by adding CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've tried for hours today, but I just cannot get this avatar image/its div to align centre - https://demo.notionware.shop/

I've tried `display: block !important` with `margin-left: 0 !important;` and margin-right: 0 !important; plus all manner of other things. But something is stopping it.

[image]

I'd be happy to consider aligning both the avatar and headline, though I know doing for the latter alone would be a simple matter of `text-align: center;`.

Note - I cannot edit or remove existing style rules from that page, only inject additional style rules that may take precedence..

```
<div class="notion-header">
   <div class="notion-header__cover has-cover">
      <div style="display:block;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0"><img alt="This Is A Test Page" src="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F234ac021-23e8-467d-9dc5-2178971f439c.jpg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=100" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 640px, (max-width: 750px) 750px, (max-width: 828px) 828px, (max-width: 1080px) 1080px, (max-width: 1200px) 1200px, (max-width: 1920px) 1920px, (max-width: 2048px) 2048px, 3840px" srcset="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F234ac021-23e8-467d-9dc5-2178971f439c.jpg&amp;w=640&amp;q=100 640w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F234ac021-23e8-467d-9dc5-2178971f439c.jpg&amp;w=750&amp;q=100 750w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F234ac021-23e8-467d-9dc5-2178971f439c.jpg&amp;w=828&amp;q=100 828w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F234ac021-23e8-467d-9dc5-2178971f439c.jpg&amp;w=1080&amp;q=100 1080w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F234ac021-23e8-467d-9dc5-2178971f439c.jpg&amp;w=1200&amp;q=100 1200w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F234ac021-23e8-467d-9dc5-2178971f439c.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;q=100 1920w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F234ac021-23e8-467d-9dc5-2178971f439c.jpg&amp;w=2048&amp;q=100 2048w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F234ac021-23e8-467d-9dc5-2178971f439c.jpg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=100 3840w" decoding="async" class="notion-header__cover-image" style="visibility:visible;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%;object-fit:cover;object-position:center 0%"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="notion-header__content has-cover has-icon-image">
      <div>
         <div class="notion-header__icon-wrapper has-cover has-icon-image">
            <div style="display:block;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0"><img alt="This Is A Test Page" src="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F6b606527-0689-4fda-8920-312dfb151148.jpg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=100" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 640px, (max-width: 750px) 750px, (max-width: 828px) 828px, (max-width: 1080px) 1080px, (max-width: 1200px) 1200px, (max-width: 1920px) 1920px, (max-width: 2048px) 2048px, 3840px" srcset="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F6b606527-0689-4fda-8920-312dfb151148.jpg&amp;w=640&amp;q=100 640w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F6b606527-0689-4fda-8920-312dfb151148.jpg&amp;w=750&amp;q=100 750w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F6b606527-0689-4fda-8920-312dfb151148.jpg&amp;w=828&amp;q=100 828w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F6b606527-0689-4fda-8920-312dfb151148.jpg&amp;w=1080&amp;q=100 1080w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F6b606527-0689-4fda-8920-312dfb151148.jpg&amp;w=1200&amp;q=100 1200w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F6b606527-0689-4fda-8920-312dfb151148.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;q=100 1920w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F6b606527-0689-4fda-8920-312dfb151148.jpg&amp;w=2048&amp;q=100 2048w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F6b606527-0689-4fda-8920-312dfb151148.jpg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=100 3840w" decoding="async" class="notion-header__icon" style="visibility:visible;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%;object-fit:cover;object-position:center"></div>
         </div>
         <h1 class="notion-header__title">This Is A Test Page</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A link to an external site is not enough to make a question a good one. Code (all the relevant HTML/CSS/JS) should be included in the question as text, preferably in a Stack-Snippet. You should read the ["How do I ask a good question"-article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Update your answer accordingly. Until then, this answer is missing details.

Comment: Understood and agreed. I have revised the question to add code. Thank-you.

Comment: All three answers appear to have the desired effect Would anyone like to debate which one should be accepted?

Comment: That decision is up to you, as the discussion would be opinion-based. However, you can (and should) still upvote all the answers that seemed helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parent with class
"notion-header__icon-wrapper has-cover has-icon-image"
needs

```
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
```

Comment: In this case, they also needed `!important`

Comment: I haven't checked, but might be the case

Answer (score 2):

I saw your demo and realized that you didnt make any changes to the parent's style of image
Try it for ″has-icon-image″ class :

```
.notion-header__icon-wrapper.has-cover.has-icon-image {
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution;

HTML

```
<div class="notion-header__icon-wrapper has-cover has-icon-image"><img src="..."></div>
```

CSS

```
.notion-header__icon-wrapper.has-cover.has-icon-image {
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
}
```

Results

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`.notion-header__icon-wrapper` has `position: absolute`, so you can give it `left: 50%`. Now it's left side is centered, but we want to center the whole `<div>`.
We can translate it by 50% of its own width to the left to make it centered by using `transform: translate(-50%)`.